# How should I create a description list with bullets?

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I have a `<dl>` description list that is unordered and therefore  should display bullets before each `<dt>`.

**Edit:** To clarify, I have an unordered list of `<dt>`-`<dd>` pairs. They should display looking like one list item, with the `<dt>` having a bullet before it.

I can think of two ways to apply bullets to this list:

1. Putting a `<ul>` around the `<dt>` and then `<li>s` around the items
2. Using the `<dt>'s` CSS :before pseudo-selector and give it the content of a bullet

Which is the better way to create a description list with bullets?

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: I would use :before. Adding <ul> and <li> tags will add unnecessary markup to your html.

Comment: Just FYI, `dt` (description title, not list) and `dd` are supposed to be siblings, not parent/child — both are children of `dl` (description list).

Comment: I believe that originally the <dt> was considered the equivalent of a bullet which is why you need to use CSS to coerce one if that is your styling preference.
Consider a dictionary, it does not precede each term with a bullet and this is the paradigm <dl> is trying to emulate.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use an un-ordered list? Is there a particular reason why you are not?

But to answer your question, you could use:

```
<dt>
   <dd style='display:list-item;'> Content </dd>
   <dd style='display:list-item;'> Content </dd>
</dt>
```

I am not sure about cross browser compatibility.

Comment: The support for `display: list-item` is not bad — IE8+ and every other modern browser, same as `:before` pseudo-element.

Comment: Personally this seems easier than `:before` I guess its more of a personal choice if both offer the same support.

Comment: Is it "proper" to put the `<dd>` inside of a `<dt>`? The validator throws an error for the `<dt>` closing tag. And I'm sorry if I didn't express my problem clearly enough: I need a list of `<dt>`-`<dd>` pairs.

Comment: <dt> and <dd> are both descendants of <dl> you SHOULD NOT have a <dd> inside a <dt>

Answer (score 0):

It appears, based on my hammering away at a similar problem, that the `<dl>` tag does not support list bullets. Which is a shame, since it *is* an html list. (And, no one seems to document that.)

Fortunately, you can interrupt a list with other blocks of code without too much difficulty. And, there's the `<br />` tag. So....

CSS:

```
ul.listPlayed {
     list-style-type: square;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="listPlayed">
    <li>1st Game<br />
    Description of first game.<br />
    <a href="#">Wikipedia</a><br />
    <a href="#">Official page</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, place all your text within the `<li>` tags, and format it within that set.